# Implement Google Maps on a Access Form

Tags: google-maps, ms-access

I'm looking for help on developing a MS Access form that has Google Maps integrated so that our drivers can look up a stop and know exactly where it is based on the Google Map.

I have wireframed (basic mockup) it like this:
[image: map]

So my question is, how can I make the right side of the screen (map), populate based on the information on the left? Do I need to pass values? Additionally, can the map auto generate, or would the user have to click a button to make that map appear?

The button "DIRECTIONS FROM SEARS TOWER" is just a filler, and would be a button for where our location is. I'm envisioning that opening as an another window.

Thoughts? Thanks again StackExchange :D

Comment: First, you should make sure you're complying with the terms of service. I assume you're using a Google Maps API for Business license for this one?

Comment: If you are sure you are compliant, you can do this with a web browser control.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done with a Web Browser Control, I just have never used that feature of Access.

Here is the link for the Sears Tower: <https://maps.google.com/maps?q=233+South+Wacker+Drive,+Chicago,+IL&hl=en&sll=41.878537,-87.636373&sspn=0.026361,0.055747&oq=233+South+Wacker+Drive&hnear=233+S+Wacker+Dr,+Chicago,+Illinois+60606&t=m&z=17>

So I would just have to pass the address into the link (basically build a link) for the Web Control to view it....but the back end of passing the address/removing spaces and Web Browser Control part of Access is unfamiliar territory for me

Comment: I think I found my answer:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHoy6hsAltc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comments above show you are well on the way to solving this one. Google maps uses + signs  as replacements for spaces. The youtube video link you provides shows a nice builder for the hyperlink. A more generic solution would be to set the Browser 'Control Source' field to:

```
="https://maps.google.com/maps?" & Replace([Address],' ','+') & ",+" & Replace([City],' ','+') & ",+" & Replace([State],' ','+') & ",+" & [Zip]
```